# Android: Relative Layout Selector Doesn't Work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-selector

I'm using a relative layout with a selector resource xml to highlight the relative layout on click. But it doesn't highlight the relative layout on click. Below i have put the corresponding selector xml, layout xml and the drawable.

Layout Code Snippet:

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/rlShare"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_new_exam"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/share_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Selector xml file:

```
<!-- Selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_selected" android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_selected" android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

Please help me with this,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: also add state like `android:state_pressed="true"` in your selector and try

Comment: you can take same image in selected or pressed

Answer (score 2):

use this code and take different image from drawable

```
 <!-- Selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_selected" android:state_focused="true"         android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- When not selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_default"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your selector:

```
<!-- Selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>

<!-- Default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_default" />
```

Notice, that in your original selector, you have the same drawables in both states.